# How to to keep track of the amount of queued samples with ALSA?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

There is a [text file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/timestamping.txt) in the Linux kernel documentation about ALSA timestamping. I copied the following quote from the file.

> The ALSA API provides two basic pieces of information, avail
>   and delay, which combined with the trigger and current system
>   timestamps allow for applications to keep track of the 'fullness' of
>   the ring buffer and the amount of queued samples.

This is very interesting for me but I have trouble to understand how to do it properly just by reading the file. I am able to get `avail`, `delay`, and timestamps but do not understand how to use them to get the amount of queued samples.

I want to get an approximation of the playback delay.

Is there an implementation of this available? Could someone explain how to this a bit more explicit?